# Laravel database notification do something on Notification::send()

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification

Is there an event that triggers when `Notification::send()` is called?
I want to call a function to send push notification when Notification::send() is called.

I'm creating a comment feature where user can mention other user with format @username, and send notification for every user mentioned.

This is my `CommentController.php`

```
use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Notifications\UserMentioned;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;

class CommentController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $note = new Comment();
        $note->content = $request->content;
        $note->save();

        preg_match_all('/@([\w\-]+)/', $request->content, $matches);
        $username = $matches[1];
        $users = User::whereIn('username', $username)->get();

        Notification::send($users, new UserMentioned($request->content));
    }
}
```

This is my notification `UserMentioned.php`

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class UserMentioned extends Notification
{
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'You have been mentioned by ' . auth()->user()->name,
            'content' => $notifiable,
        ];
    }
}
```

This is my function to send push notification. There will be other controllers as well. So where can I call this function once for every `Notification::send`?

```
public function sendNotificationFCM(array $deviceKey, String $title, String $body)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $serverKey = 'my-server-key';

    $notification = [
        'title' => $title,
        'body' => $body,
        'sound' => 'default',
        'badge' => '1',
    ];

    $arrayToSend = [
        'registration_ids' => $deviceKey,
        'notification' => $notification,
        'priority' => 'normal',
    ];

    $json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: key=' . $serverKey,
    ];

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a section of the documentation dedicated to this subject...

https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/notifications#notification-events

You can listen for `Illuminate\Notifications\Events\NotificationSent` and fire whatever class you like.